# Creating combinations from a tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, combinations

I take the data from the database. From the database they come in the form of a tuple:

```
[('test1', 'test12', 'test13', 'test14'),
('test21', 'test22', 'test23', 'test24'), 
('test31', 'test32', 'test33', 'test34'), 
('test41', 'test42', 'test43', 'test44'), 
('test51', 'test52', 'test53', 'test54'), 
('test61', 'test62', 'test63', 'test64'), 
('test71', 'test72', 'test73', 'test74'), 
('test81', 'test82', 'test83', 'test84'), 
('test91', 'test92', 'test93', 'test94'), 
('test11', 'test12', 'test13', 'test14')]
```

And that's what I want:
make combinations of these input... so the output I had a combination of 4 parameters (such as in example) and...

**1)** most importantly, new combinations,the values were always in its place, i.e. if in the original combinations the values were index [1], this means that in the new combination, it should also be [1]...

**2)** there are no duplicate combinations

As example:

I got tuple:

```
[('test91', 'test92', 'test93', 'test94'), 
('test11', 'test12', 'test13', 'test14')]
```

And from this I got new combinations:

```
[('test91', 'test12', 'test13', 'test14'), 
('test11', 'test92', 'test93', 'test94')]
```

Maybe it's possible to do using the method of pairwise or something else.
Help.

Comment: so you want combination of all the tuples, that's gonna be a lot.

Comment: Yes there are lot of combinations possible.

Comment: Brute force approach: Use four nested loops to catch all possible combinations. There are n^4 possible combinations (n being the number of rows of your 4-tuple array)

Comment: Even using recursion we can do it. Thats easy way..

Comment: @jrook but how it's implement....

Comment: It should be implemented just like he said: nested loops (or `itertools.product()` which is equivalent ot that)

Comment: do take transpose `newlst = [i for i in zip(*lst)]` and then bruteforce it `op = list(itertools.product(*newlst))`

Comment: @Abhishek if you want to create list from `zip()` you just need to `list(zip())`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) method from builtin package [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools) which gives cartesian product of input iterables.

Here is code that do what you desire. 
**But be careful**, because huge list would produce a ton of combinations, try not to run out of memory.

```
from itertools import product


data = [('test91', 'test92', 'test93', 'test94'), 
('test11', 'test12', 'test13', 'test14')]

b = list(zip(*a))  # making list of n-th elements
# b = [('test91', 'test11'),  <- first elements
# ('test92', 'test12'),  <- second elements
# ('test93', 'test13'),  <- third elements
# ('test94', 'test14')]
variations = product(*b)
output = set(variations) - set(a)  # this is unique variations without input data
#  output = {('test11', 'test12', 'test13', 'test94'),
#  ('test11', 'test12', 'test93', 'test14'),
#  ('test11', 'test12', 'test93', 'test94'),
#  ('test11', 'test92', 'test13', 'test14'),
#  ('test11', 'test92', 'test13', 'test94'),
#  ('test11', 'test92', 'test93', 'test14'),
#  ('test11', 'test92', 'test93', 'test94'),
#  ('test91', 'test12', 'test13', 'test14'),
#  ('test91', 'test12', 'test13', 'test94'),
#  ('test91', 'test12', 'test93', 'test14'),
#  ('test91', 'test12', 'test93', 'test94'),
#  ('test91', 'test92', 'test13', 'test14'),
#  ('test91', 'test92', 'test13', 'test94'),
#  ('test91', 'test92', 'test93', 'test14')}
```

If you want output to be with input data you can simply

```
output = set(variations)
```

If you need a list instead of set, just do

```
output = list(output)
```